# JavaScript var declaration style - susceptible to ASI?

Tags: javascript

In my coding style I generally tend to have the commas for comma separators before the next value, example:

```
var x
   ,y
   ,z
```

I find this is easier to assimilate as the pattern when broken is obvious to the human eye.

Question - is this likely to fall foul of [automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) - I read this linked question and it was not obvious after a couple of readings so I decided to ask.

[EDIT] I voted to re-open this question. My point is that whilst the answer can eventually be pulled from the linked question, it is not at all obvious. I linked to the same question as was proposed as duplicate as I had found it to be the best discussion of the overall ASI concept. Summary - I don't think the answer to my question is clear in the linked question therefore, this question should stand.

Comment: No (according to the thread you provided)

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks. You are possibly correct but it was not obvious so I asked the question for clarity and to get input from other peoples experience, and after a search for the answer in SO.

Comment: I didnt closed it. I hoped somebody who really knows it would clarify this, but well...